# How would one securely store passwords in a way they're are still readable by an app?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

I have an app that pulls information from another website using the user's credentials for that website. The problem is, in order for it to work my app has to know the actual username/password of the user.

I'm trying to come up with some way to securely store their passwords, always encrypted, but my app needs to be able to read them. They will be stored in a MySQL database.

My main concern is to have something secure enough that if somehow the database gets compromised, the hackers wouldn't  be able to read/decode the user/password information.

I was searching on how companies store credit card information and I would go from there, but I couldn't find an explanation clear enough..

How is it done? How should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: use a hash. md5() is built into php, so store the md5 in the database, then compare the md5 of a login attempt with that

Comment: @RedAlert , my users should "save" their password on my app once. So there won't be passwords to compare with the MD5 hash, since they won't login more than once. After they save their password my app has to be able to read them from the database, however I'm looking for some way to protect the passwords instead of having them in plain-text in the database.

Comment: I would recommend using something stronger than `md5`

Comment: To build upon what @RedAlert is suggesting, I'd recommend [reading this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: I think that password hashing wouldn't work as the users won't input their password every time so there won't be any passwords to compare. (It's one way).

Comment: Why wouldn't users be using their password each time, out of curiousity? Through a 'remember me' function?

Comment: in that case, a good solution might be encrypt the password using AES, with their password for your app used to generate the secret key. That  way, no one with access to just your database would be able to get it.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Sorry for the confusion. Imagine an app that pulls data from Twitter. Usually you login with your Twitter account and that's it, you don't have to login every time with your twitter account for the app to be able to pull your data from Twitter. That's because of an API. The problem is, this website that I'm pulling data from doesn't have an API, so I have to use the users' passwords to login and pull the data from this website to my app. I don't want to force the users to input their passwords every time my app updates its information pulling data from that website.

Comment: @RedAlert that sounds nice. Where can I find an explatanory or guide of how to do that using MySQL and PHP ?

Comment: @viniciusmunich-AssabetTech: Ahh, I think I understand you now. In that case, I'd go along with Red Alert's solution (encrypting the password with AES, secret key, all that jazz).

Comment: take a look at http://php.net/mcrypt . Specifically, `mcrypt_encrypt` and `mcrypt_decrypt`. To generate a good `key`, just run a popular hash on the user's password (for your app). You can technically use the user's raw password for `key`, but that can potentially be very weak and easy to bruteforce

Comment: @viniciusmunich-AssabetTech I'd build that API. Having your user passwords compromised is a far bigger deal...

Comment: @DickW - Although, if the other site isn't under his control, then that would be an issue.

Comment: @viniciusmunich-AssabetTech Do not, I repeat "**DO NOT**" use `md5` for password hashing. It's old and too "fast" and can easily be hacked. The technology [**dates back to 1996**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). Use another method, just not that one.

Comment: @RedAlert Please refrain from further pawning off `md5`. It's [**old**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and easy to hack. The other one you suggested is indeed much better >>> http://php.net/mcrypt as is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a hash because it's one way.  Maybe encryption (AES, maybe??) is what you're looking for.  They'd be encrypted before being written to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is hash the password when you store it in the database. When a user attempts to log in, your application will hash the password that they provide, then check the database for a matching username/hashed-password pair.

I'd suggest defining a function that would let you hash a password in a consistent manner:

```
<?php

function hashPWD($in) {
  $out = $in;
  for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $out = hash('sha256', $out);
  }
  return $out;
}
```

---

Another thought, since you mentioned an app, is to generate some sort of session identifier when a user successfully logs in (based on credentials, timestamp and any identifying information for the device). On the successful login attempt, you write to a sessions table, and any transaction that your front-end makes with your back-end sends that session identifier, along with device information.

Comment: While I agree that hashing passwords is the way to go, I would say that using your 'own' hash function is not a best practice. Even if you hash something a thousand times, it may still be easily compromised. Please see [this discussion at security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33531/why-improvising-your-own-hash-function-out-of-existing-hash-functions-is-so-bad). I would suggest using a well-known library, such as [PBKDF2](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: @DickW: That's fair; along with that, if the asker is using PHP 5.5, it appears that [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) is available.

Comment: yep, and PHP 5.5 even has a [PBKDF2 implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) itself. Great stuff.

Comment: (@DickW: if you'd like to edit my answer, please feel free to; I've marked it as CW)

Comment: you did not read / fully understand the question. the OP said he needs the users cleartext password to log in to ANOTHER service.

Answer (score 0):

well, guess I have bad news:

if there is no other way than your app having to know usernames and cleartext passwords of users so you can log in to that other service, there might be no really safe solution.

you can either store them cleartext, which is obviously bad.
Positive here: it is OBVIOUSLY BAD, not HIDDEN BAD.

you can encrypt them and store the ciphertext. BUT: as you have to have the key available somehow on the server to be able to decrypt the ciphertext when your service needs the cleartext, this isn't much better than cleartext as likely someone hacking into your server could get the cryptokey also.

if you can invest some effort in a special solution, maybe special crypto hardware like a TPM or crypto smartcard could help, as this stuff is made for safe key storage, so someone breaking into your server might not be able to read out the key. BUT: in the same way as your app decrypts stuff using that hardware, an attacker likely could do the same if he is root on your server.

that said, what you could do is to make the service / server as safe as it gets in all other ways (like general system, network and web security, having good software development practices, etc.).

Also you should tell your users that for giving them that functionality, there is no other way than to store their password in some not very safe way. And that of course they need to use different passwords everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to make your mysql_query string in order to insert the entered password into a database. Below, I do this with a function. You will have to define your user table in your database as 'users' for this code to work. I use the hash function to encrypt.

```
$register_data = array(
'password'  => $_POST['password']
// Add other user stuff here, e.g. 'username' => $_POST['username']
);
function register_user($register_data) {
array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
$register_data['password'] = hash($register_data['password']);
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
    }
```

Now, to the form for the password.

```
<form>
<label>Enter your password!</label>
<input type="type" name="password">
```

Notice how the input is defined as password. 
This should work well for a register script.

Comment: this won't work. the password is for an external site, not his own, so storing the hash is useless